# Determining Left and Right Table Boundary Position

Tags: vba, ms-word, position

I need to know the left and right boundary position of a table. I tried various combinations of Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage), but that appears to give the position of text within the table, and hence is dependent on cell padding and left/center/right justification.

I want the left and right table border position.

It seems this should be simple. For instance, the table knows where to draw it's boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the position of the table's range not the selection.

`ActiveDocument.Tables(n).Range.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)` will give you the position for a specific table.

`Selection.Tables(1).Range.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)` will give you the position for the table that contains the selection.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!!   Just tried it out, and it works exactly as desired.

Very much appreciated!!